# Novel where a kid learns psychic powers by squeezing little cubes with binary numbers on them?

Tags: story-identification, psychic

I recall a novel where a kid learns psychic powers by squeezing little cubes with binary numbers on them?

Does anyone remember this story from my childhood?

Comment: see OP confirmation comment for answer below

Answer (score 8):

This is [Christopher and his Magic Powers](http://bookstore.iuniverse.com/Products/SKU-000074949/Christopher-and-His-Magic-Powers.aspx) by Richard Koff.

> Christopher is 13 and often too smart for his own good. He hates
>   school and can’t seem to stay out of trouble. On a dare he knocks on a
>   door to a house all his friends say is haunted and meets a strange,
>   quiet man who calls himself the Headmaster. The Headmaster starts
>   Christopher on a series of lessons unlike anything he was taught in
>   school. He learns how to move objects with his mind alone, how to read
>   other people’s thoughts, he becomes invisible or shrinks to the size
>   of a pencil. It’s not just for fun. The Headmaster has a mission for
>   Christopher that will change his life forever.

Mention is made in [this mini-review](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-465997.html) of the binary blocks

> The book is basically about a boy who bravely knocks on the door of a
>   supposedly haunted house, wherein he meets "The Headmaster", a
>   mysterious person who knows an awful lot about Christopher. Over the
>   course of the book, he helps Christopher develop his mental abilities,
>   with the aid of some little gold cubes with binary numbers on them (I
>   still think of this book when I use binary).

Comment: OMG you are amazing!! Yes, that's the one. Thank you so much!!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM - Don't forget to upvote and click the "accepted" button.